# LINQ update column in table 1 with id from table 2 where emails match?

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I am trying to update the `DonorID` column, set as `foreign key`, in my Email table with the value of the `DonorID` column, `primary key`, in my `Donor` table.

The `Donor` table holds all distinct email addresses from donors, adding any new addresses to a new row as they come into my Email table, and gives the `Donor` an `ID`. I want to update each `DonorID` in my Email table, currently set to `0`, to match the corresponding `DonorID` from my `Donor` table.

I can query the tables to return a result showing all matching email addresses but I can't figure the logic to update my Email table to reflect the new `DonorID` associated with that address in my `Donor` table.

Here is the code I have so far...

```
        //join rows based on sender address
        var join = from emai in db.Emails
                   from dono in db.Donors
                   where emai.Sender == dono.Email
                   select new{ Sender = emai.Sender, EID = emai.DonorID, DID = dono.DonorID };
        gvJoin.DataSource = join;
        gvJoin.DataBind();

        // Query the database for the row to be updated.
        var query = from ema in db.Emails
                    where ema.DonorID == 0
                    select ema;

        // Execute the query, and change the column values
        foreach (Email ema in query)
        {
            ema.DonorID = 1;
        }

        // Submit the changes to the database.
        db.SubmitChanges();
```

I know it should be simple, but I am simple too so any help would be appreciated :)

**Donor Table**

```
DonorID  |       Email  
---------+---------------------       
  1      |  user1@domain.com    
  2      |  user2@domain.com    
  3      |  user3@domain.com    
  4      |  user4@domain.com    
  5      |  user5@domain.com
```

**Email Table**

```
DonorID  |      Sender  
---------+---------------------            
  0      |  user1@domain.com    
  0      |  user2@domain.com    
  0      |  user3@domain.com
  0      |  user4@domain.com    
  0      |  user5@domain.com
```

Just to give an idea of how my table data currently looks. I can't post images of my `DBML` but there are more fields in each table. I just won't be using them in this query, I think.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You mean something like this?

```
foreach (Email ema in query)
{
    ema.DonorID = join.FirstOrDefault(j => j.Sender == ema.Sender).DID;
}
```

Comment: It works flawlessly, you sir are my hero for today :) Thank you kindly.